http-toolkit : Connection aborted even though I'm using the security config
Edit:

It seems it's a bug in Flutter. Last answer by @Tim Perry has more details.
I ended up using android studio network profiling for my needs.

I installed the http toolkit on my machine, and using an android in a device emulator.
I followed the official http toolkit guide, created network_security_config.xml file, added it to AndroidManifest.xml, and installed the CA certificate, but I keep getting connection aborted messages for my app.
Not really sure what to do or how to even debug it.
Any tips/guides will be great!
The guide:
https://httptoolkit.com/docs/guides/android/#if-you-dont-have-a-custom-network-security-config
The network security file is just the same as that guide, didn't have anything before.
Using flutter, but it's just java - nothing special about it.
Note:
I'm using an emulator with google play so I can't use the system CA, as written in the http toolkit guide
Adding screenshots of the http toolkit app on the device.



"I followed the guide" - which guide. First, when talking about external tutorials and similar things please always at least link them. Second please include the relevant parts of your network security config xml file. Third, you should give more details on the used app: what technology is used (java, Kotlin, ReactNative, Xamarin/MAIU, ...).

@Robert - Edited the post with the details.
But tl&dr: offical guide, exactly same file as in that guide (didn't have one before), and using flutter with java.

So you have created network_security_config.xml, added it to AndroidManifest.xml and installed the root CA certificate of http-toolkit?

@Robert yup, exactly.

Then please write it in your question and as mentioned in my first comment please give more details about your app. Some app frameworks ignore network_security_config.xml therefore we need to know more details. Also check if you can see http sites in chrome (e.g. http://neverssl.com) to make sure your proxy set-up works at all.

@Robert edited the question with those details, and also attached 2 screenshots of the http toolkit from the device emulator - one includes an http site, which I'm assuming it's the same test you wanted, but let me know if you want me to test neverssl.com anyway
and there aren't any more details on the app - it's just a simple flutter app.
I'll google for flutter, but afaik it doesn't ignore teh network_security_config.xml or any xml file.

This is due to Flutter, which ignores external certificate configuration (on Android and all systems, as far as I'm aware). https://github.com/flutter/website/issues/2472 has more details, and there are plenty of related issues like https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140737 that closely match your setup here.
To resolve this in the short term, you'll need to modify the certificate trust within your Flutter app directly, since network_security_config will be ignored. In the long term, this is a Flutter bug and you should pressure them to correctly follow the system settings.

Awesome, thanks!
I ended up using Android Studio network profiling, but it's definitely good to know that.
